# Run all UnitTests from multiple DLLs

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2022

I have a Visual Studio 2022 Solution with several UnitTest projects (DLLs). The individual projects are working fine (Native UnitTests for VisualStudio). Now I would like to create an EXE project that runs all UnitTest projects of all DLLs.

Can someone give me a hint how to run all UnitTests?

Thanks a lot
Markus

Comment: Just use a build tool (make) or at least a script (can be as simple as a batch file) to run all your tests in sequence.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you have an example of such a script?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I have what matches your test setup. The C++ tests I worked with so far compiled directly into exe's. How do you run an individual test now?

Comment: I first tried to build my tests as individual EXEs. But that led to errors. Therefore I have switched to DLLs. This works. Which main() do you use in your tests?

Comment: The main is more-or-less auto-generated by the testing framework. I had used qtest and cpptest, but I guess both of them are quite outdated as of now.